# Unpacking a dictionary dictionary parameter, and using **kwargs in mutiprocessing pool

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, keyword-argument

all!

Normally, if I need to pass a dictionary to a function as parameter set, One simple way of doing that is through unpacking the dictionary and use them.

```rb
def some_function(a=0, b=0, **params):
    print(a) # 1
    print(b) # 2

d = {"a":1, "b":2}
some_function(**d)
```

I am working on a little project that will take very long time. So, I was trying to use `Multiprocessing` to help me get the job done faster. I simplified my code (below).

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat
import time

def some_function(n, param1=0, param2=0):
    #some operation on n and **params
    print(n)
    print(param1)

input_k = [i for i in range(1,10,2)]
input_params = {'param1':1, 'param2':1}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(16) as p:
        k = p.starmap(some_function, zip(input_k, repeat(input_params)))

############## output ##############
#1
#7
#9
#5
#3
#{'param1': 1, 'param2': 1}
#{'param1': 1, 'param2': 1}
#{'param1': 1, 'param2': 1}
#{'param1': 1, 'param2': 1}
#{'param1': 1, 'param2': 1}
```

I wanted to run that `some_function` on the corresponding `input_k` and `input_params`. But the output of the function is not as expected. It looks like the function take whole `input_params` dictionary and assigned it to `param1` in the function?

I know I did not unpack the dictionary as I pass it to the function, but I don't know how to do that(`zip()` doesn't allow me to simply add "**" to `the input_param`). How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from itertools import repeat
import time

def some_function(n, param1=0, param2=0):
    #some operation on n and **params
    print(n, param1, param2)

input_k = [i for i in range(1,10,2)]
input_params = {'param1':1, 'param2':1}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(16) as p:
        k = p.starmap(some_function,  [[x,*y.values()] for x,y in zip(input_k, repeat(input_params))])
```

And is now working fine.